# Работа в Atom по FTP через прокси

Tags: ftp, proxy, atom

Работаю в Atom через прокси. Ставлю пакеты, обновляю.
Теперь понадобился FTP. 
У меня на работе стоит прокси сервер.
При установке пакетов, к примеру Remote-FTP, и попытки соединения с ftp сервером, соединения не происходит.
В Winscp к примеру все нормально работает.

Настройки прокси для apm указаны в ~/user/я/.atom/.apmrc
Т.е. когда их там не было. Обновлять и качать пакеты в Atom я не мог.

Куда прописать прокси для работы по FTP в Atom? Возможно ли вообще это.
Или пакеты не поддерживают такую возможность и могут соединяться только на прямую.

Comment: Судя по пути - у Вас линукс (или в худшем случае мак). В этом случае попробуйте подключиться с помощью fuse. То есть, просто подмонтировать ftp себе в папку. После этого Вам больше не нужны будут никакие плагины и настройки. А пара заготовленных скриптов решат все остальные проблемы.

Comment: @KoVadim Спасибо, буду смотреть